# Por que tengo esta Advertencia: Parámetro desconocido?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

tengo este error

DataTables warning: table id=Table - Requested unknown parameter 'usuario' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

aqui esta la funcion en donde me esta arrojando el error, que es exactamente en esta linea
**datatableInstancia.row.add(data1).draw();**
pero no se ocmo solucionarlo entiendo que tiene un dato nulo  pero no se como resolverlo.. una ayuda por favor mil gracias...

estoy intentando crear una datatable dinamica.

```
function getTabledata(objetivo) {
    debugger
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("getPodioTL", "ConsultaTL")',
        method: 'Get',
        dataType: "json",
        data: { objetivo: objetivo },
        success: function (data) {
           
            var data1 = JSON.parse(data);
           
                //obtener el nombre de los encabezados usando nombres clave
                var headerName = Object.keys(data1[0]);
                //construir encabezados de tabla html fot
                var headderHtml = MakeColumnHeaderHtml(headerName);
                var columns = [];
                //añadir el encabezado de la tabla con id
                $('#Table').append(headderHtml);
                // crear una definición de columna
                // para colocar los datos en el mismo nombre de columna
                for (var i = 0; i < headerName.length; i++) {
                    columns.push({ "data": headerName[i] });0
                }
            
                //inicializar la tabla de datos con definición de columna
            var datatableInstancia = $('#Table').DataTable(getDatatableDef(columns));
                //ahora el último paso para agregar datos en datatable
                datatableInstancia.row.add(data1).draw();
       
        }
          
    });


}
```